# Windows 10 Anniversary Update and Unsigned Driver

Tags: windows-10, driver

We're developing a mini-filter driver for Windows 10.
Until the anniversary update, we were able to move windows to Test mode and run our unsigned driver for debugging before releasing a version.

As we understand from the docs, this has been disabled since the anniversary update.

How are we to test our driver then?

Thanks!

Comment: cannot you see? windows is helping you :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Driver Signing changes in Windows 10, version 1607](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_hardware_certification/2016/07/26/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10-version-1607/):

```
Q: **How do I sign drivers during development and testing?**

A: Please see the Signing Drivers during Development and Test
topic on MSDN for information on how to test sign. In addition,
if Secure Boot is set to OFF, then drivers signed with existing
cross-signed certificates will continue to be valid.
```

The referred link is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/signing-drivers-during-development-and-test--windows-vista-and-later-). See also [Driver Signing Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/kernel-mode-code-signing-policy--windows-vista-and-later-)

**TL;DR:** Create a test certificate, install it on your test machine as a trusted certificate, and sign your test driver and/or catalog file with it.

> And to be fair, this has been the recommended practice since 2006 with Windows Vista. There was just a common workaround people used instead to keep sticking with totally unsigned drivers. 10 years does seem to be sufficient notice.